# "Verifying" method for a form doesn't make an error show up

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

I have a standard, straightforward code for authenticating an user:

```
# controller
  val addForm = Form(
    tuple("email" -> nonEmptyText, "password" -> nonEmptyText)
      .verifying("Invalid email or password", result => User.authenticate(result._1, result._2).isRight)
  )

  def add = Action { Ok(views.html.session.add(addForm)) }


  def create = Action {
    addForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      failure => BadRequest(views.html.session.add(failure)),
      success => Redirect(routes.Home.index)
        .flashing("key1" -> "You have logged in.")
    )
  }
```

I expected it to show me an error if NOT `User.authenticate(result._1, result._2).isRight` but there is no error showing up. Yes, authentication works well but there are no errors when it fails.

```
@helper.form(action = routes.Session.create()) {

    @helper.inputText(form("email"))
    @helper.inputText(form("password")) 
    <!-- ........... -->
  }
```

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have a check in your view along the lines of

```
@if(addForm.hasErrors) { ... }
```

For example, a basic layout might be:

```
@if(addForm.hasErrors) {
  <div class="alert-message error">
    <p>Please correct the following:</p>
    <ul>
      @addForm.errors.map { error =>
        <li>@error.key @error.message</li>
      }
    </ul>
  </div>
}
```

Comment: if I want to highlight all the elements inside `@helper.form(action = routes.Session.create()) {` of red color, how do I do this?

Comment: or, how do I "add error" to each email and password at the server side?

Comment: Hi Alex, not sure exactly what you mean, but I use classes (like "alert-message" above), the great "inspect element" functionality of chrome, the info on [this page](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaForms) to figure stuff like this out. Oh, and also the play [sample apps](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Samples).

Comment: I mean, if I do this `@if(addForm.hasErrors) {
  <div class="alert-message error">` it will show me only the list of errors without making each control red. I want each control (password and email in my case) to become red.

Comment: The play helpers will add the class "error" to input fields that have errors, so that should work, if you have a style defined for class "error". Take a look at the computer-database sample app.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have key in form to  display this error, thats why error is not showing up

Try this in failure  case for nonEmptytTxt validation, email and your custom validation
 BadRequest(views.html.sesion.add(failure.withError("password","Invalid email or password")))